# Ruby on Rails Testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I added a controller action using the Rails testing technique, however despite solving all the errors of the new controller action created, a new error regarding the already existing controller actions appeared. Could anyone have an idea of how to go about it? This is the error I'm receiving on my terminal:

```
Error:
StaticPagesControllerTest#test_should_get_help:
ActionView::Template::Error: Permission denied @ rb_file_s_rename - (C:/Users/ADMIN/Desktop/sample_app/tmp/cache/assets/sprockets/v4.0.0/Ah/AhRKfpIltIZZsQQ3DW_RRap2qgrZpmLfGMuTS7wKLvE.cache.16460.9436.19047, C:/Users/ADMIN/Desktop/sample_app/tmp/cache/assets/sprockets/v4.0.0/Ah/AhRKfpIltIZZsQQ3DW_RRap2qgrZpmLfGMuTS7wKLvE.cache)
    app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:9
    test/controllers/static_pages_controller_test.rb:10:in `block in <class:StaticPagesControllerTest>'
```

Comment: Just change the permissions or the owner of the tmp folder in `C:/Users/ADMIN/Desktop/sample_app`.

Comment: It's unclear how this is related to Grails.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was I changed this code in the test_helper.rb from:

parallelize(workers: :number_of_processors, with: :threads)

To:

parallelize(workers: 1)
Its works!